# Visual Studio Express 2012 annoying pop-up dialog on thrown exception

Tags: exception, popup, visual-studio-2012, modal-dialog, breakpoints

**Problem description:**

Whenever an exception is thrown and not catched a dialog pops up. I want Visual Studio Express 2012 just to break and stop grabbing all my input with this modal dialog window. Example of the dialog: [image]

**Wanted solution:**

VS **2010** does not show this annoying pop-up window but something called exception assistant. How an I can get the same type of break on exceptions in 2012 as in 2010? Even if that's not possible I really want the pop-up to be **gone** while keeping the break.

**Things I've tried to solve this problem:**

1. Search for a solution on both Google and here on StackOverflow (some of the keywords I used: visual studio 2012, pop-up, window, dialog, exception assistant, exception, break)
2. Run repair on VS 2012
3. Uninstall and delete settings (folder: C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012) followed by an install
4. Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> "Reset all settings"
5. Enable the "Break when exception type is thrown"
6. Change settings in the: "Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General"

Edit:

I'm using the Express edition, [no exception assistant anymore](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762652/enable-exception-assistant-option-missing-from-vs2012-express-for-desktop)! :(

Edit2:

Found a (very ugly) workaround using AutoHotkey:

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent
loop
{
    WinWaitActive, Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
    WinClose, Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
}
return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of answers on the following forum, VS 2012 Express no longer has the exception assistant option:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762652/enable-exception-assistant-option-missing-from-vs2012-express-for-desktop

Hopefully we'll see it back in future versions of VS Express. VS 2010 Express is still available to my knowledge, and 2012 can read 2010 projects without destroying compatibility. So if it's a big deal to you, you can go back to 2010 to trace the bugs. Not a particularly exciting solution, but I'm still impressed that Microsoft has given out as many features as they have in the Express editions.

Answer (score 2):

In VS2012, when I unchecked Tools -> Options ->Debugging -> General -> "Enable Exception Assistant" I get the annoying dialog box.