# Break on error but supress dialogs on exception or assertion failure in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2012

Is there any way to get Visual Studio (I'm using 2012) to break on the offending line of code when there is an unhandled exception/assertion fails *without* first displaying the Abort, Retry, Igore or the Break, Ignore, Continue dialog, while also redirecting its error messages to the debug output window? I'm working with native C++ code.

There does not seem to be any option to do this and the [`_CrtSetReportMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448(v=vs.110)) function does not have any effect on my system.

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761800/visual-studio-express-2012-annoying-pop-up-dialog-on-thrown-exception) is about managed code so it is of no assistance.

I am asking because I really don't want to have to click through one or two dialogs when something goes wrong if I'm already running an application in the debuggger. If memory serves me, other IDEs, such as Xcode, break by default without any unnecessary and annoying popups.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick way to toggle 'break on all exceptions' in VS2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291811/quick-way-to-toggle-break-on-all-exceptions-in-vs2012)